# Increase space between specific columns in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

How do I increase the white space here between Column B and Column C (but not Column A and Column B)? I'm after something that will let me target a column very specifically, so I probably want inline CSS.

```html
<html>

<style>
  th {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column A</th>
    <th>Column B</th>
    <th>Column C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you should tell me how you define `white space` like percentages or what else

Comment: `table td:not(:first-child) { padding-right: 1em; }`

Comment: Thanks but this just seems to make Column B and Column C wider, without adding to the white space between them. Also note that I've now added this to my query: "I'm after something that will let me target a column very specifically, so I probably want inline CSS."

Comment: Ah, you're right. Looks like increasing __cellspacing__ on a single column requires dummy table cells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192918/2743458

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   td,
   th {
       border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
       padding: 10px;
      }

   td {
       text-align: center;
      }

   tr:nth-child(even) {
                        background-color: #eee;
                      }

   th[scope=col] {
        background-color: #696969;
        color: #fff;
                 }
   table {
           border-collapse: collapse;
           border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
           letter-spacing: 1px;
           font-family: sans-serif;
           font-size: .8rem;
        }

 </style>
 <table>

<tr>
     <th scope="col">Column A</th>
     <th scope="col">Column B</th>
     <th scope="col">Column C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but note that I've now added this to my query: "I'm after something that will let me target a column very specifically, so I probably want inline CSS." I actually have quite a large table where I want extra space between a few specific columns, and there's no clear underlying pattern to where I want them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
       th{
          background-color: #D8D8D8;
          }
        td,
         th {

             padding: 10px;
            }

          td {
             text-align: center;
             }
        table {
           letter-spacing: 1px;
           font-family: sans-serif;
           font-size: .8rem;
          }

    </style>
   <table>

    <tr>
     <th>Column A</th>
     <th>Column B</th>
     <th style="width: 0.1rem;background:none !important;"></th>
     <th>Column C</th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <th style="width: 0.1rem;background:none !important;"></th>
      <td >3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <th style="width: 0.1rem;background:none !important;"></th>
      <td>3</td>
     </tr>

  </table>
```